# SQL COUNT within same select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if its possible to count the records produced by a query within the same query?

```
SELECT HousesForRent.City
FROM HousesForRent
WHERE rooms >= 7

SELECT COUNT(rooms) AS seven_or_More
FROM HousesForRent
WHERE rooms >= 7;
```

I'v only managed to create it in another `SELECT` query.

Comment: So, what would you expect the output to look like?

Comment: A  total at the end of the results, if that is possible.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and make that clear. *Show* what the output data would look like.

Comment: if you want to have only one line you want to use UNION

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to use the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT  HousesForRent.City, COUNT(*) OVER() Total
FROM    HousesForRent
WHERE   (rooms >=7 );
```